# MYSQL select from additional tables in database, match data etc

Tags: mysql, case, mysql-error-1064

I have this query that works just fine, however I want to change my database table a little bit, so I need to change my query a little bit. My working query is this:

```
$notificationsq = mysql_query("
SELECT
    N.*,
    P.*,
MAX(N.date) AS newDate


 FROM
    notifications N,
    posts P

WHERE
    N.userID='$session'
AND
    (
            (
                   N.action='1'
                AND
                   (N.state = 0 OR N.state=1)
             )
            OR
                N.action='2'
     )
AND P.state='0'
AND
    N.uniqueID=P.id
GROUP BY
    N.uniqueID
ORDER BY
    N.state ASC,
    newDate DESC

") or die(mysql_error());
```

Now, what I'm doing is changing the row "uniqueID", so what I need to do is basically:

```
if(action==2){unqiqueID=C.postID} else {uniqueID=N.uniqueID}
```

Here is my table structure:
i41.tinypic.com/nyzolg.png

---

The information from the photo is:

```
Table: Notifications

id  UserID  FromID  UniqueID    Action  State   Read_Date   Date
1   1       2       1           1       0       0           1325993600
2   1       6       2           1       0       0           1325993615
3   1       2       1           2       0       0           1325993622
4   1       6       2           2       0       0           1325993661
5   2       6       2           2       0       0           1325993661
```

Action = 1 means UniqueID identifies a row in Posts;
Action = 2 means UniqueID identifies a row in Comments.

```
Table: Posts

id  ToID    FromID  Post        State   Date
1   1       2       Hey         0       1325993600
2   1       6       okay yeah   0       1325993615

Table: Comments

ID  PostID  FromID  Comment     State   Date
1   1       2       lol         0       1325993622
2   1       6       ohh         0       1325993661
```

So, in the Notifications table where action is 2, the UniqueID's are for the 'id' in the Comments table.
What I want to return is the PostID, so in the query it would just be as if the UniqueID was this instead:

```
1
2
1
1
1
```

But the UniqueID would stay the same where Action is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reference a calculated column in the `WHERE` clause of the same SELECT statement. Usually this can be worked around by using a subselect like this:

```
SELECT
  * /* or list the necessary columns specifically */ 
FROM (
  SELECT
    ...
    some_expression AS columnAlias,
    ...
  FROM ...
)
WHERE ...
  AND columnAlias = ...
```

As you can see, the column calculated by `some_expression`, `columnAlias`, can be accessed in the outer SELECT using its alias.

But you are pulling rather many columns here, and using masks too, so trying to use a subselect might cause a name clash. Try to reduce the number of columns being pulled by specifying them explicitly.

---

**UPDATE**

Based on further explanations in comments, here's what I would probably do in your situation:

```
SELECT
    P.id AS uniqueID2,
    MAX(N.Date) AS newDate,
    MIN(state) AS state,           /* or maybe 'AS minState', if you like */
    MAX(N.Read_Date) AS lastRead,  /* just another example to illustrate the
                                      point that most columns in this query
                                      should be selected with aggregating */
    ...  /* other columns as necessary */
FROM notifications N
    LEFT JOIN comments C ON N.action = 2 AND N.uniqueID = C.id
    INNER JOIN posts P ON N.action = 1 AND P.id = N.uniqueID
                       OR N.action = 2 AND P.id = C.postID
WHERE N.userID = '$session'
    AND (N.action = 1 AND N.state IN (0, 1) OR N.action = 2)
    AND P.state = 0
GROUP BY P.id
ORDER BY
    state ASC,    /* No 'N.' prefix here because now it is a reference
                     to the MIN(state) column, which has the same name.
                     If it looks too confusing, use a different alias for
                     the column and change this entry accordingly. */
    newDate DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, would you possible be able to use my code to put something together to show me what you mean? That would be great thanks.

Comment: @DylanCross: To be honest, your query doesn't make much sense to me at the moment. I can see that you are trying to match `P.id` either with `C.postID` or with `N.uniqueID` depending on a certain condition. And it's the condition that confuses me most. Could you please explain what you are trying to do? I might suggest a different approach there but first I'd like to understand what is going on there.

Comment: Ok, N.uniqueID is where C.postID used to be stored. Now it is the unique id of the comment in the comments table. Here's a photo. http://i41.tinypic.com/nyzolg.png

Comment: @DylanCross: Please check my update. And thanks for the clarification. Your illustration may be worth incorporating in your original post: someone else might come up with a better idea using that information.

Comment: That looks good, but what else do I need to add to make it work how I want it to, and in addition keeping the other functionality as well?

Comment: @DylanCross: I thought I was following the details given in the picture and the result should be according to what you would expect. I only omitted the majority of the columns from the SELECT clause apart from the most relevant, but you may add them as you see fit. And in all other respects this is how I would go about achieving your goal. Please let me know what particularly you think I am missing here.

Comment: Okay, I actually just spent a few minutes going through it adding the few parts you mentioned you hadn't added, and I just had to change my code around a little, and change some names to get it to work, and it's working perfectly, with one minor exception. It doesn't return "state" as "0" if a comment, "action = 2" is new, "state=0", hopefully that makes sense. I haven't been able to figure out the spot to change that yet, so perhaps you could.

Comment: @DylanCross: Oops, I mixed up `action = 1` and `action = 2` in the WHERE clause, sorry. Updated my answer.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have any effect on the "state", it still returns 1, when it should return 0

Comment: Maybe there exist both 1s and 0s for the conditions specified, and if you haven't included `state` in GROUP BY and are not aggregating it, the results for that column should be unpredictable. Is this the case?

Comment: That's true, there are both 0s and 1s present. So I'm not quite sure how to implement this into the code you gave me, because in the code i posted first, it worked as expected.

Comment: I can assure you that it was as unreliable in your code as it can be in mine if you do not take proper measures to make it otherwise. If you want the value to be 0 when the group contains both 0 and 1, select `MIN(state)` instead of `state`. Again, columns that are not included in GROUP BY, should not be selected without being aggregated, or their values are unpredictable (with one exception, though: all the `P.*` columns  in your query *are* reliable, because they correlate directly with `P.id`, which is included in GROUP BY, but all other columns should be aggregated, or omitted altogether).

Comment: Here's a relevant article that explains the issue: [GROUP BY and HAVING with Hidden Columns (MySQL)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

Comment: Oh, thanks. As you can tell MYSQL is my weak point, more specific to these sorts of queries, what would it take to add this into that code? I've tried a few things but haven't been successful.

Comment: Well, actually it looks like I got it, and it looks like everything is working as it should. Thank you veryyy! much for all your help with this, if you want to still go through and put your suggested code for this that would be good, to make sure I got it right.

Comment: I can see that your original query pulls many columns (all of them, actually) from the source tables, but do you really need them to be that many? `P.id` and `MAX(N.Date)` seem definitely necessary, `state`, or rather `MIN(state)`, should probably also be included in the output, as per your comments, but how about others? What other columns *must* be in the output and what values do you expect them to have to make sense for the result set? Remember that they may contain various values for the same `P.id` and only one is going to be selected: either you make sure which one or it will be random.

Comment: Oh yes, I see what you mean with that, I think I've got them taken care of.

Comment: Added a couple more columns to my query for better illustration.

Comment: Thank you, you've been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put uniqueID2=P.id in a HAVING block instead in a WHERE block. I'm sure it will work.

David Lyons,
ehtu.com

Comment: Thank you, this sort of works, however it's just returning 1 result when there should be at least 3 or 4.